# Why Ext.MessageBox gets stuck after several clicks on "Ok" button?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use MessageBox of ExJS framework to show dialog with "Ok" button.

```
// app.js
function showNoteMessage (title, message, fn, scope) {
    return Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Title example',
        message: 'Message text',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        promptConfig: false,
        fn: function () {
            if (fn) {
                fn.apply(scope, arguments);
            }
        },
        scope: scope
    });
}

// index.html
<button onclick="showNoteMessage()">Open dialog several times</button>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open dialog with provided two buttons "Ok" and "Cancel".
2. Click on the "Ok" button
3. Open dialog one more time.
4. When you click on "Ok" one more time, the dialog gets stuck on the screen and unlock all content behind it.The buttons inside the dialog are disabled.

Current version Ext.js 2.4.2.571.

After click on "Ok" button or "Cancel", gray background disappears and dialog gets stuck with unlocking content under it. I try to wrap Ext.Msg.show into setTimeout but it looks like it works only locally.

### Update

I continue working on this bug and found out that issue can be in this function:

```
// MessageBox.js

...
onClick: function(button) {
    if (button) {
        var config = button.config.userConfig || {},
            initialConfig = button.getInitialConfig(),
            prompt = this.getPrompt();

        if (typeof config.fn == 'function') {
            button.disable();
            this.on({
                hiddenchange: function() {
                    config.fn.call(
                        config.scope || null,
                        initialConfig.itemId || initialConfig.text,
                        prompt ? prompt.getValue() : null,
                        config
                    );
                    button.enable();
                },
                single: true,
                scope: this
            });
        }
    }

    this.hide();
},
...
```

For some reason on the step with broken click it skips this part of code:

```
            this.on({
                hiddenchange: function() {
                    config.fn.call(
                        config.scope || null,
                        initialConfig.itemId || initialConfig.text,
                        prompt ? prompt.getValue() : null,
                        config
                    );
                    button.enable();
                },
                single: true,
                scope: this
            });
```

Comment: You have provided little data to reproduce the problem.Please, create fiddle which reproduces your problem.  
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

Comment: thank you for this advise, I've updated the code here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/351c. But it looks like I have super old version of ExtJS (2.4.2) and with latest this bug doesn't reproduce. Maybe it's related to version. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I've updated the description of this bug accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to the old version of ExtJS. I was not able to update it, so found a workaround: to disable animation like this:

```
 // app.js
 ...
 Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.showAnimation = false;
 Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.hideAnimation = false;  
 ...
```

Comment: Thx, was struggeling with popups not disappearing in an old sencha touch application when running in iOS UIWebView, disabling animations worked for us.